# Function with promise inside not return result

Tags: javascript, promise

i'm new to promise in JS and i don't understand why my function don't return the expected result.

Here is my code:

```js
// Extract firstname actor form .docx to JSON

var mammoth = require("mammoth")
var fs = require('fs')

function pdocx (filepath) {
    
    return mammoth.extractRawText({path: filepath})
    .then(function (res) {
        return res.value;
    })
    .then(function (res) {
        let arr = {}
        arr["episode"] = [...new Set(res.match(/(?!Episode #)(\d+)/))]
        arr["names"] = [...new Set(res.match(/^[^:\r\n]+(?=:)/gm))]
        console.log(JSON.stringify(arr, null, '\t'))
        return JSON.stringify(arr, null, '\t')
    })
}

console.log(pdocx("doc.docx"))
```

The console.log in the function display the good result:

```
{
"episode": [
    "10600"
],
"names": [
    "Hilary",
    "Jean-Claude",
    "Devon",
    "Jean Claude",
    "Cane",
    "Lily",
    "Jack",
    "Phyllis",
    "Victor",
    "Nikki",
    "Neil",
    "Paul",
    "Dr. Barrett",
    "Christine",
    "Kelly"
]
```

}

but i have error on the console.log outside the function :

```
    Promise {
  _bitField: 0,
  _fulfillmentHandler0: undefined,
  _rejectionHandler0: undefined,
  _promise0: undefined,
  _receiver0: undefined }
```

Thanks for your help !

EDIT:

It works when i do this, but not sure it's the cleanest way to do promises:

```js
function pdocx (filepath) {
    
    return mammoth.extractRawText({path: filepath})
    .then(function (res) {
        return res.value;
    })
    .then(function (res) {
        let arr = {}
        arr["episode"] = [...new Set(res.match(/(?!Episode #)(\d+)/))]
        arr["names"] = [...new Set(res.match(/^[^:\r\n]+(?=:)/gm))]
        return JSON.stringify(arr, null, '\t')
    })
}

pdocx("doc.docx").then(function (res) {
    console.log(res)
})
```

Comment: Capture the object... `a = function(){}.then().then()` Or in your case, `b=pdocx()`

Comment: @Nishant That won't do anything useful either.

Comment: @deceze won't that function `pdocx` return a `promise` whose value will be settled with the result.. i.e the json output here?

Comment: Yeah, sure, then `b` is the promise. Still doesn't give you the value.

Comment: b.then for any results... Ah it is not same as return maybe. Will read up on the answer. Thanks.

Comment: Yes, `pdocx("doc.docx").then(console.log)` *is* the clean way.

Comment: @Bergi and all Thank you !